# Salesforce Activities - Task and Events - Reporting

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When building a report on Activities (Tasks and Events), I had a Subject of Introduction.

I know that I have hundreds, but when I create a Report, it is only returning 8.

I removed all other fields from the report, made sure the filters were All Activities.  Date: All Time, and all other filters were set to show me all data, not just my data.

Any advice on what I might be missing in my report?

Thanks,
Jason

Created the report using Lighting and Searched Activities, then selected Tasks and Events.

Expecting to see more than 8 items with the Subject of Introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You may be a victim of archived activities. Can you see these Tasks/Events all right on the record itself just like that or are they "below the fold", you need to click "view all"?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities_archived.htm&type=5

> Events that ended more than 365 days ago,
> Closed tasks due more than 365 days ago ,
> Closed tasks created more than 365 days ago (if they have no due date)

If that's the case - you can contact SF support to increase the limit: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385669&type=1

If you're after an one-off export - maybe API access will be faster than support route, check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385173&type=1 out.